# Define a packed version of a C struct

Tags: c, gcc, struct

I have a C structure defined somewhere outside my code. Can I define a packed version of the same structure? If I define my own structure from the start, that is easy:

```
struct test {
    // members
} __attribute__((packed));
```

I defined a simple structure and tried two possibilities, this:

```
struct test {
    int x;
    double y;
    char z;
};

struct test_p {
    struct test __attribute__((packed)) s;
};
```

and this:

```
struct test {
    int x;
    double y;
    char z;
};

struct test_p {
    struct test p;
} __attribute__((packed));
```

However, neither of these work (both compile fine though) printing sizeof(struct test_p)=24 on my system (I use gcc 4.8.2 on a 64-bit machine) which is the same as sizeof(struct test). Is there a way to achieve the desired effect?

Just in case you were wondering: I want to parse packets received over network which are just packed structures. The thing is, I can't modify the header file because it is a part of a third-party library, and the structure itself contains too many fields to copy them one by one. I can certainly copy the structure definition to my own header and make the packed version -- actually it is the solution I'm using now -- but I was just wondering if there is a more concise solution which does not involve copying the whole definition.

Comment: An interesting question, but I don't think you'll find an elegant solution; "You may only specify this attribute on the definition of an enum, struct or union, not on a typedef that does not also define the enumerated type, structure or union." https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Type-Attributes.html

Answer (score 2):

The gcc has introduced the `__attribute__((packed))` precisely to *avoid* the dangerous effects you are seeking: the definition of the structure should binary compatible between all the user applications and libraries which use the same definition.

But the gcc also provides a way to do the packing [the old fashioned, dangerous way](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure-Packing-Pragmas.html) - `#pragma pack(push,n)` and `#pragma pack(pop)`. It would work reliably only if the 3rd party header file contains solely the structure definition, or you do not use anything else from the header. Use them like that:

```
#pragma pack(push,1)
#include "theheader.h"
#pragma pack(pop)
```

Otherwise, I personally would have simply copy-pasted the structure definition, renamed it, and added `__attribute__((packed))` in my own header. Packing with pragmas the whole header is really a dirty hack. And 3rd party headers might change in unexpected ways, contributing to [the bit rot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_rot).